# Run monaco editor without web workers in totally synchrounous mode

Tags: monaco-editor

I want to integrate monaco into third party web site. I don't have access to the server where the site runs.

The site has strict Content Security Policies applied. I can't add javascript from other domain and use web workers.

I was able to create a separate js package with monaco, webpack and worker-loader in order to generate an inlined script for web workers. However, even in that case, it throws

> "Refused to create a worker from 'data:application/javascript,%2F**...."

Is it possible to create a js package with monaco, which doesn't use web workers? I'm able to inject single script into a page using chrome add-in, but web workers fails every time..

Comment: Ended up with https://github.com/nolanlawson/pseudo-worker which works perfectly for my scenario.